# Jquery or CSS: Set static, unchangeable height for div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm using Adsense responsive banner and I'm having one problem. My css is set to keep the maximum height of the outer div to `160px;` and is using `display:inline-block;`, it's a pretty simple code:

```
<div style="display:inline-block; height:160px; width:100%">
  <div>ADSENSE RESPONSIVE (Comes as inline-block)</div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the banner is expanding the outer div's height and that should not happen. Is there any approach using jquery or css that I could use to set that height static and unchangeable, no matter what's inside and without using css `overflow`?

EDIT
Here's what's happening:
[image]

FULL CODE

jQuery + HTML:

```
    <div id="adsenselisting">
    <div id="adsenselistingadvert">



    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <!-- Responsive Adsense In Listing -->
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
    style="display:block"
    data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    data-ad-slot="6429507759"
    data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({})});
    </script>



    </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
/* FLUID HEIGHT LAYOUT FOR ADSENSE */
#adsenselistingadvert { margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; max-height:100%;  border:2px solid blue;   }

#adsenselisting {  display: inline-block; width:100%; max-width:100%;  padding-top: 12px; padding-bottom: 12px;   border:2px solid red; }




    @media only screen and (min-width : 1px) {
    #adsenselisting, #adsenselistingadvert { height:100px }
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {
    #adsenselisting, #adsenselistingadvert { height:130px }
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
    #adsenselisting, #adsenselistingadvert {  height:130px }
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width : 640px) {
    #adsenselisting, #adsenselistingadvert {  height:160px }
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width : 720px) {
    #adsenselisting, #adsenselistingadvert {  height:200px}
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width : 960px) {
    #adsenselisting, #adsenselistingadvert {  height:200px }
    }
```

Everything works just fine, I just want the height not be expandable.

Comment: `.classofouterdiv img {max-width: 100%}` this will prevent your banner to overflow its parent by proportionately resizing it.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `overflow`? What do you expect to happen if the content is too big to fit in the height you've specified?

Comment: If I use `overflow` the adsense banner will just expand inside the hidden area, and that will hide part of the banner, making it against Google TOS.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay How's that solution supposed to work? Will it keep the height static?

Comment: if you keep the `height` static it will surely **stretch your banner image**, best way to manage its dimensions proportionately is to use `max-width`

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to use overflow, set a fixed height on parent, and on child set `max-height:100%` which will keep the height of the `banner` at maximum th height of it's parent. see snippet below

i also added a height of `300px` on the `banner` for example purposes. so you can see that it doesn't go out of the div

```css
.fixedheight {
  border:2px solid red;
   box-sizing:border-box;

}

.fixedheight >div { 
height:300px;
border:2px solid blue; 
max-height:100%;
display:inline-block;
 box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixedheight" style="display:inline-block; height:160px; width:100%">
  <div>ADSENSE RESPONSIVE (Comes as inline-block)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: "no, that's exactly what should happen by default. the parent gets it's height from the content inside it." I didn't say it shouldn't happen by default. What I mean is that that's not the result I need.

Comment: ok. sorry. i understood it wrong :) will edit my answer. is my solution working for you ?

Comment: do you have an image there ? or what didn't work ? because in my example using your code, it works :) can you share full code ? relevant html plus CSS

Comment: with your code, it works ( but i cannot load the ad in the jsfiddle ) https://jsfiddle.net/xcjhq3ju/

Comment: Tried your solution, same thing. It looks like it's no use to use css for this case. Perhaps jQuery could solve it.